# No Module Named PyQt5 and Pyside2 Error While Trying to open rqt

Tags: ros, rqt

I've been trying to use the ROS(Robot Operating System) using this page:

[Tutorial page](http://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-CLI-Tools/Introducing-Turtlesim/Introducing-Turtlesim.html)

In the link it makes you use turtle sim it seemed to work fine with me without any errors.

In the 4th step(install rqt),i get this error:

`INPUT: RQT

OUTPUT: ImportError for 'pyqt': No module named 'PyQt5'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide2'`

There was more lines of error but it seemed irrelevant to me because it only says file names.
I'm using python version 3.8.3 and qt version 5.12.12.

I downloaded the qt manually in their website.Didn't use:

```
pip install PyQt5
```

And i don't exactly remember now but someone said something about local files of pyhton but i had none of them:
[screenshot of C:\Users\Boran\AppData\Local\Programs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDCTg.png)
It supposed to be Pyhton files in here.
Also there is no problem about python it works fine and i used talker and listener(pyhton coded applications of ROS.) and they worked fine.

Comment: This isn't a PyQt issue

Comment: Then what's the issue?

Comment: Your issue is that you have installed your libraries in a place that python isn't looking for them.  If I were you I would reinstall python but use the installer from the official python website.  Then reinstall pyqt5 with pip, then do whatever you need to do with rqt

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I'll wait for a simpler solution because i added many programs connected to pyhton and if reinstall pyhton i have to reinstall and setup those programs too.

Comment: The only other solution is to make python look for your libraries where they are located and you are the only one who is capable of telling you how to do that since only you hae access to your filesystem and can figure out where everything is saved

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing graphviz.It appears that to run rqt i had to install graphviz.